# Spark update column value in a Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

What would be the best equivalent with Spark dataframes to SQL

***`update table1 set colx = "some value" where coly in (select coltab2 from table2 where [another condition)]`***

I have some working solution but I am really not very satisfied with it. Looks really cumbersome and I hope I miss a simplier way

First I get the value for the where clause (there could be thousands so I don't wand to use a collection)

```
val df2 = xxxx.select("coltab2")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [coltab2: string]
```

this dataframe contains all the values I want to retain in the where clause

Then I perform a left outer join with table1 to add coltab2 on `df2.coltab2=df1.coly`. If the value of added coltab2 is not null this means that it was present in table2 so I use this condition to update another column from original table1 (df1) and then drop this added column coltab2 that served only as a condition to update another column

```
val df_updated = df1.join(df2, df1("coly") === df2("coltab2"), "left_outer").withColumn("colx", when(!isnull($"coltab2"), "some value").otherwise(col("colx"))).drop(col("coltab2"))
```

Hope I am completly wrong and there is a more efficient way to do it ;)

Comment: it seems to be perfect solution. There are two improvements to be done. 1 instead of left_outer join you can simply use left join and 2 .otherwise(col("colx")), colx is just being and cannot be used in when .

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is a neat solution with good readability.  If wanted, you could explore another approach using RDD.  With the assumption that your column list is not big, you can `collect` the column list into a `set` and map `colx` in `df1` accordingly as follows:

```
val df1 = Seq(
  ("x1", "y1"), ("x2", "y2"), ("x3", "y3")
).toDF("colx", "coly")

val df2 = Seq(
  ("y1"), ("y3"), ("y5")
).toDF("coltab2")

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val colList: Set[String] = df2.rdd.map{ case Row(c: String) => c }.collect.toSet

val dfUpdated = df1.rdd.map{
    case Row(x: String, y: String) => (if (colList contains y) "some value" else x, y)
  }.toDF("colx", "coly")

dfUpdated.show
+----------+----+
|      colx|coly|
+----------+----+
|some value|  y1|
|        x2|  y2|
|some value|  y3|
+----------+----+
```